# percolation problem (java -cannot run appropriately)

Tags: java, algorithm, montecarlo, union-find

I have a problem relating to the percolation model with the latest version of Java

My project includes three file a illegalargumentexception.java file (use to handle illegal arguments), a percolation.java file (the datatype), and the PercolationStats.java file (use to calculate and generate the statistic)

In my expectation, the code should generate the probability of the percolated model (after a specific time of trials)

And here is my code:

the percolation datatype:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;

public class percolation {
      
    public static boolean[] grid;                        
    public static WeightedQuickUnionUF  gridMap  ;                            
    public static int openCell;              
    public static int top = 0;       
    private static int current_index;
    public int bottom;
    private int n;
    public percolation(int n) {
    }

    // creates n-by-n grid, with all sites initially blocked 
    public int Percolation (int n) {  
       
        gridMap = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n + 2);
        grid = new boolean[n*n + 2];
        this.n =n;
         openCell = 0;
        top = 0;
        bottom = n*n +1;
        if (n <=0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Grid's number can not negative or equal to zero");
        }
        return n ;
    }
    
    // opens the site (row, col) if it is not open already 
    public void open( int row, int col) {
        current_index = (row-1)*n + (col-1);
        grid[percolation.current_index] = true;
        percolation.openCell++;
        if (row == 1) 
            gridMap.union(percolation.current_index, top);
        if(row == this.n) 
            gridMap.union(current_index, col);
        

        if (row > this.n || col > this.n)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of bound");
    
        if (row <1 || col <1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The index must be greater than zero");
        
        if(row >1 && isOpen(row-1, col)) // above cell
         {
            assert(current_index > n);
            gridMap.union(current_index,current_index-n);
        }


        if (row < this.n && isOpen(row + 1 , col))  // below cell     
        {                                       
            assert(current_index + n < n * n);                                       
            gridMap.union(current_index , current_index + n);                                   
            }
        if(col > 1 && isOpen(row, col - 1))  //left cell
            {                                       
            gridMap.union(current_index,current_index- 1);                                   
                }
        if(col < this.n && isOpen(row, col + 1))  //right cell
         {
            gridMap.union(current_index,current_index + 1);
        }
        
        return ;
    }

    // is the site (row, col) open?
    public boolean isOpen(int row, int col) {
      return grid[current_index];
    }

    // is the site (row, col) full?
    public boolean isFull(int row, int col) 
    {
        if(!isOpen(row,col)) return false;                                                       
        return gridMap.find(current_index) == gridMap.find(top);  

    }
        
    public int numberOfOpenSites()  // returns the number of open sites 
    {
        return percolation.openCell;
    }

    // does the system percolate?
    public boolean percolates() {
        return gridMap.find(top) == gridMap.find(bottom);
       
    }
   
    // test client (optional)
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }



}
```

the PercolationStats.java file

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdStats;
public class PercolationStats {
  
    
   public static double[] result;
   public static int trials;
        // perform independent trials on an n-by-n grid
        public PercolationStats(int n, int trials) {
                
           
            double[] result = new double[trials];
            int test_row ;
            int test_col ;
            for (int i=0; i <trials; i++) {
             percolation per =  new percolation(n);
             while (!per.percolates()) {
                test_row = (int)((StdRandom.uniformInt(n)*n) +1 );
                test_col = (int)((StdRandom.uniformInt(n)*n) +1 );
                
                if( !per.isOpen(test_row,test_col) ) 
                    per.open(test_row,test_col);
                
             }
             result[i] = (double)(per.numberOfOpenSites()) / (n * n);
            }
            
                if(n <= 0 || trials <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must greater than zero");
        }
    
        // sample mean of percolation threshold
        public double mean() {
            
            return StdStats.mean(result);

        }
    
        // sample standard deviation of percolation threshold
        public double stddev() {
            return StdStats.stddev(result) ;

        }
    
        // low endpoint of 95% confidence interval
        public double Low_confidence() {
            return (mean() - (1.96 * stddev())/ Math.sqrt(trials));

        }
    
        // high endpoint of 95% confidence interval
        public double High_confidenceHi() {
            return mean() + (1.96 * stddev())/ Math.sqrt(trials);

        }
    
       // test client (see below)
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        PercolationStats s = new PercolationStats(50,10000);
        System.out.println("Mean:" + s.mean());
        System.out.println("Standard Deviation:"+ s.stddev());
        System.out.println("High Confidence" + s.High_confidenceHi());
        System.out.println("Low Confidence" + s.Low_confidence());
       }
    
    
}
```

My expectation is when I compile the PercolationStats file it will generate the result of the percolating probability threshold like this: (the result if you give the input 200 by 200 grid and try the simulation 100 times

```
~/Desktop/percolation> java-algs4 PercolationStats 200 100
mean                    = 0.5929934999999997
stddev                  = 0.00876990421552567
95% confidence interval = [0.5912745987737567, 0.5947124012262428]
```

but my result is a bunch of errors that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF.find(int)" because "percolation.gridMap" is null
        at percolation.percolates(percolation.java:93)
        at PercolationStats.<init>(PercolationStats.java:17)
        at PercolationStats.main(PercolationStats.java:58)\
```

I believe this is to be caused by the percolate datatype, and to be more specific is the line:

```
public boolean percolates() {
        return gridMap.find(top) == gridMap.find(bottom);
       
    }
```

It states that the gridMap variable of Union-Find is null - I don't know why this happens, I speculate this can relate to the scope of the "gridMap" variable, which is not applicable to all methods in the datatype. That is my hypothesis It could be wrong.

**Can anyone give me a clue for why this happens and what should I fix for the successful compilation (I means to generate the probability)**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set `gridMap`, though it is mentioned in a method called `public int Percolation (int n)`. Perhaps you intended that `Percolation` is called from body of the constructor which you declared as `public percolation(int n)`.

The fix should be simple: move the `public int Percolation (int n)` code into the constructor or make constructor `public percolation(int n)` call `Percolation(n)`.

The class should follow conventions and renamed to `Percolation`.

Comment: Also note that gridMap and some other fields are declared `static` - so should not be initialised in a contructor. It looks like they should be declarated as instance members.